# Dumping urban airship and getting unexpected response

Tags: java, tomcat, urbanairship.com

I am using urban airship for my push notification. But many times in my server log i got error "java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpcted response" status code:401 responseBody - authorization Required. ( In Image ). Is there bug with urban airship? Please can any body guide me in proper way.

[image: This is error message i got in server log]

Comment: Firstly, please post exceptions as text, not images, so that they are searchable. Secondly, are you sure you're using all of the necessary credentials?

Comment: Hi @AndyTurner i edit question as you guide. and yes i am using all of the necessary credentials. In fact my push notification works fine but getting this error some time in server console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your error, the authentication string is either incorrect or missing. [Urban Airship's documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#push) states that your authentication needs to be your master authentication string:

> Authorization: Basic

Also, here is their full response code list:

http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/overview.html#response-codes

> 401 Unauthorized: Authentication information (the app key & secret) was either incorrect or missing

Comment: Appreciate your answer @dperconti , But if my (the app key & secret) was either incorrect or missing it should not be work for all push notification request. But i mentioned in my question this error comes once in thousands requests.

Comment: you were right but i don't know how it can be change, i set up my key very initial stage that time it's working now don't know how it was changed and i again fixed and working now. Thanks.